# Temporarily changing HTML structure on the same page in PHP when submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have PHP page that have submit button to another URL.

I want to reload the current page after the <kbd>submit</kbd> button clicked, and add `div` to the HTML.

My page url is: `/foo.php`, and in the HTML I have:

```
<button onclick="$.get('/bar', function() { ... })">Submit</button>
```

As you can see the form sends request to `/bar` page.

I want to reload the `/foo.php` (the current page), and change the HTML to:

```
<button onclick="$.get('/bar', function() { ... })">Submit</button>
<div>Thank you!</div>
```

My problem is how can I know that the user click on the button and the refresh was because the click, and not because just navigating.

Another thing, if it possible, I want that the new `div` will disappear if the user refresh the page again.

Comment: `$.get('/bar?button_was_clicked=true', ...)`

Comment: this is like a flash session behavior

Comment: Does `foo.php` have to actually refresh or is it okay if the DOM is just manipulated to show the `div`?

Comment: Just utilize the `success()` callback and append a div to your form.

Comment: `<button onclick="$.get('/bar', f..` come on, these inline js..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could simulate a flash session (one time use session) if you opt to do this in PHP. Consider this example:

**foo.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form method="POST" action="bar.php">
    <button type="submit" name="thank_you">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['thank_you'])): ?>
<?php unset($_SESSION['thank_you']); ?>
    <h1>Thank You!</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**bar.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['thank_you'])) {
    $_SESSION['thank_you'] = true;
    // processes
    header('Location: foo.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just append the div in the success callback of the get function? You wouldn't have to reload the page.

```
<div id="btn_area">
    <button onclick="$.get('/bar', function() { $('#btn_area').append($('<div>').html('Thank You');)})">Submit</button>
</div>
```

By the way, i hardly recommend to separate the javascript from the html and not put it directli in the DOM.

Another Method would be, to fire an additional form with a hidden parameter to the same side. After that, you check on the serverside the hidden parameter and display the div.

A third method is, to set a cookie in the Callback, reload the side, check the cookie, display the div and remove the cookie again.

In my opinion, the first mentioned option (add the div directly in the callback without reloading) would be by far the 'prettiest', but of course i don't know what else is going on on your site

Comment: `$('div')` will append any div's it finds on the page. `$('<div>')` will create a new div to append. You want the later.

Comment: @scragar You're right, of course. I corrected my answer. Thank you

Comment: so i recommand to add a hidden form with a hidden field and fire it to the same side, by $('#formid').submit(); in the callback

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/CWVb9/1)**

You can handle that in js side. Just make your request, and in callback, you can manipulate dom. You can see below;

```
<button>Submit</button>

$("button").on("click", function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   $.get("/echo/html", function() {
       $button.after("<div>Thank you!</div>");
   });
});
```